# On a certain "obvious" implication concerning odd perfect numbers

Tags: inequality, perfect-numbers

Let $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ be an *odd* perfect number given in Eulerian form (i.e., $q$ is prime with $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n) = 1$).  ($\sigma(x)$ gives the sum of the divisors of $x$, and $y$ is perfect if $\sigma(y) = 2y$.)

In this [paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html), it is shown that the inequality $n < q$ is sufficient for Sorli's conjecture that $k = 1$ to hold.

Somebody pointed out to me that it is *obvious* that the following implication is true:

> > $$\sigma(n) \leq q^k \Longrightarrow k = 1$$

Is it indeed so?  It's not obvious to me for two reasons:

> > 1. $$n < q^k \Longrightarrow \left\{n < q \Longleftrightarrow k = 1\right\}$$
> > 2. $$k > 1 \Longrightarrow q < n$$

That is, in order to prove the supposedly *obvious* claim, it would suffice to show that the condition

> > $$q < n < q^k$$

never holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting back to my correspondent, the claim that

$$\sigma(n) \leq q^k \Longrightarrow k = 1,$$

where $N = {q^k}{n^2}$ is an odd perfect number given in Eulerian form, has been retracted.